# Infinetly derivable function such that $|f^{(n)}(x)| \leq \alpha|f^{(n-1)}(x)|$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Let $f:[0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ be a function that is infinitely derivable, $f(0)=0$ and $|f^{(n)}(x)| \leq \alpha|f^{(n-1)}(x)|$, $\forall x \in [0,1]$ and $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}^*$, where $\alpha \in [0,1]$ is a fixed number and $f^{(n)}$ represents the $n$-th derivative of the function $f$.

Prove that $\exists N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $|f(x)| = \displaystyle{\frac{x^N}{N!}}$, $\forall x \in [0,1]$.

I am not really sure why this function must have the expression $|f(x)|=\displaystyle{\frac{x^N}{N!}}$. By writing $|f^{(n)}(x)| \leq \alpha^{n-1}|f(x)|$ I may think that $f$ can be a polynomial, but if $|f(x)| = \displaystyle{\frac{x^N}{N!}}$, why can't other polynomial also verify the hypothesis? Also, when $n \rightarrow \infty$, then a derivative of the function $f$ will be $0$, so $f$ may have the expression of a polynomial.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it was true then we would have $f(x) = \pm {x^N \over N!}$ for some $N$. This would imply
${x^{N-1} \over (N-1)!} \le \alpha {x^N \over N!}$, or, for $x >0$,
$1 \le \alpha {x \over N}$, which cannot hold.

In fact, we can show that $f=0$.

Since $f(x) = f(0)+\int_0^x f'(t) dt$, we have
$|f(x)| \le \int_0^x |f'(t)|dt \le \alpha \int_0^x  |f(t)|dt$.
It follows from the Bellman Grönwall inequality that $f=0$.